# User and organization management in Azure AD and Azure B2C

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

After a lot of research I am still confused about using Azure AD. Here is what I want to achieve.

We maintain users in following order in SQL Server

- Organization

  - Team

    - User

There can be multiple organizations and a user can be belong to multiple organizations but his/her role will be different like Agent or Team leader or Team manager.

I want to move away from this structure and create the same in Azure AD and authenticate users via Identity provider. How to maintain same sort of structure in Azure AD?

I am looking for an solution with minimal code changes. Any thoughts on this??

Comment: Is there a single organization or can there be multiple organizations? Can a user belong to multiple teams (or organizations in case of multiple organizations)? What purpose does an organization serve? Please edit your question and include these details there only instead of comments.

Comment: @GauravMantri Please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can use Groups in AAD to achieve something similar.

Currently, the following scenarios DO support nested groups:

- The concept (you can add groups as members of other groups)
- Group membership claims (when an app is configured to receive group membership claims in the token, nested groups the signed-in user is a member of are included)
- Conditional access (when scoping a conditional access policy to a group)
- Restricting access to self-serve password reset
- Restricting which users can do Azure AD Join and device registration

The following scenarios DO NOT supported nested groups:

- App role assignment (assigning groups to an app is supported, but groups nested within the directly assigned group will not have access), both for access and for provisioning
- Group-based licensing (assigning a license automatically to all members of a group)
  Office 365 Groups

See the [product feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15718164-add-support-for-nested-groups-in-azure-ad-app-acc) and add your suggestions if you need something more complex than what AAD currently supports.